# why are rotateX and rotateY on the incorrect axis

Tags: css

I've been experimenting with an animation on my site that uses the `rotateX` and `rotateY` functions of the `transform` property.

I've found that – for some reason – they both seem to be using the incorrect axis'; rotating on **Y** will rotate *left and right*, and rotating on **X** will rotate *up and down*.

Why is this? To my surprise, I had a quick search and couldn't find anything, even on the [transforms spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/).

```css
div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.vertical{
  background-color: red;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateX(20deg);
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.horizontal{
  background-color: blue;
  transform: perspective(100px) rotateY(20deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="vertical"></div>
<div class="horizontal"></div>
```

Comment: *Why is this?* --> with no code and demo no one can answer the question

Comment: @TemaniAfif It's not a case of it being something that *isn't working* to do with my code. It's a question of why CSS fundamentally works like that – not why *my code* works like that.

Comment: Because `rotateX` rotates *around the X axis*, for example.

Comment: @TylerRoper Exactly. Left and right. *Not* up and down. See codeblock.

Comment: No, *not* left and right. Imagine your square had a *horizontal line running through it*, e.g., the X Axis. Rotating over a horizontal axis results in a vertical rotation. Think about a Foosball player; horizontal axis running through them, thus they rotate vertically.

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) is a link to the Wikipedia article on Cartesian coordinate system. As clearly depicted by the image at the top of it, X axis is horizontal while Y is vertical.

Comment: @InSync That is exactly my point. Why does the CSS spec rotate X vertically – but Y horizontally?

Comment: Don't confuse *around* with *in the direction of* . Taking the x (horizontal) axis. Rotating *around* the axis produces vertical motion. A wheel rotating around a horizontal axel (axis) rotates in the vertical plane.

Comment: @JonP That's the perfect explanation, thank you. Please make an answer so I can give you some rep :-)

Comment: For future readers: [Visual explanation](https://codepen.io/InSyncWithFoo/pen/NWLVMMK).

Answer (score 1):

The rotateX and rotateY functions indicate around which axis the rotation will occur, not in which direction.

When using the rotateY function, the rotation will occur around the y-axis of the element being transformed. This means that if you want the element to appear to rotate left and right, you need to rotate it around the y-axis. Similarly, when using the rotateX function, the rotation occurs around the x-axis of the element being transformed, so it will rotate up and down.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotateX) are some examples of how rotateX works

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse *around* with in the *direction of* . Taking the x (horizontal) axis. Rotating *around* the axis produces vertical motion. A wheel rotating around a horizontal axel (axis) rotates in the vertical plane.